# ¿Cómo concatenar celda por celda 2 dataframes?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente data frame

```
A

1 2 1

2 1 2

B

1 1 1

2 2 2
```

Necesito la concatenación de los anteriores celda por celda

```
C

11  21  11

22  12  22
```

Comment: Bienvenido Keyrun a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Keyrun A y B son columnas de un mismo data.frame? Tienen formato de número o de texto (lo puedes checar con la función `str(df)`).  Estas tratando de concatenar el primer dígito de A con el primer dígito de B, luego el segundo con el segundo..etc?

Answer (score 1):

Para esto [`mapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mapply), que aplica una función a múltiples listas y/o vectores, y ya que un `data.frame` no es más que un conjunto de listas (cada columnas) podemos hacer algo como esto:

```
A <- data.frame(c1 = c(1,2), c2 = c(2,1), c3 = c(1,2))
B <- data.frame(c1 = c(1,2), c2 = c(1,2), c3 = c(1,2))

mapply(paste0, A, B)

     c1   c2   c3  
[1,] "11" "21" "11"
[2,] "22" "12" "22"
```

Estar atento a las dimensiones, ya que en el caso que los dos `data.frames` difieran en el número de columnas o en el de filas, la función no fallará, obtendremos un warning, y los columnas o filas que falten serán completadas reciclando valores.